Set custom order status while PayPal authorization expires
Orders that are paid for via PayPal Express Checkout will automatically update to a "Payment Expired"(Custom order status) if the order has not been invoiced before the PayPal authorization for payment expires.
Currently, when the PayPal authorization expires, an order is automatically reverted to the "processing_received" status.
